# How to enforce queue to NOT run on main thread in Swift unit tests

Tags: swift, multithreading

There are many examples on how to enforce code to run on main thread. I have an opposite need for unit testing purposes. I want to exclude main thread from taking on some work.

Why do I need this: I would like to test that a particular function runs correctly, specifically when it's simultaneously called from 2 or more **background** threads (while main thread is free and available). This is because function itself makes use of main thread, while it is a typical use case that it will be called from background threads, possibly concurrently.

I already have one test case where one of the calling threads is the main thread. But I also want to test the case when main thread is not busy, when 2 or more other threads call the function.

The problem is that there's seems no way to leave main thread free. For instance even if queue is defined with `qoc: .background`, main thread was still taken:

```
private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "bgqueue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
let iterations = 10
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { _ in

    queue.async { 
        callMyFunction() // still may run on main thread, even with 1-2 iterations
    }
}
```

The only approach I can think of is blocking all threads at the same spot (using [CountDownLatch](https://github.com/uber/swift-concurrency/blob/master/Sources/Concurrency/CountDownLatch.swift) for example), and then proceed to function from all threads, but main:

```
let latch = CountDownLatch(count: iterations)

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { _ in

    latch.countdown()
    latch.await()
    if !Thread.isMainThread {
        callMyFunction()
    }
}
```

The problems here are 1 - have to make sure `iterations < available threads`; 2 - feels wrong to block main thread.

So is there any better solution? **How to exclude main thread from picking up `DispatchQueue` work within unit tests?**

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not dispatching to the main queue (or some other queue that uses the main queue as its “target”), `async` will never use the main thread. There are some interesting optimizations with `sync` which affect which thread is used (which isn’t relevant here), but not for `async`. The asynchronously dispatched task will run on a worker thread associated with that QoS, not the main thread.

So, go ahead and insert a thread assertion in your test to make sure it’s not on the main thread, and I think you’ll find that it is fine:

```
XCTAssertFalse(Thread.isMainThread, "Shouldn't be on main thread")
```

---

That having been said, you allude to the fact that “function itself makes use of main thread”. If that’s the case, you can easily deadlock if your test is blocking the main thread, waiting for the called functions to finish processing on the main thread as well.

You can often avoid these sorts of unit test deadlocks by using “expectations”.

```
func testWillNotDeadlock() throws {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "testWillNotDeadlock")
    someAsyncMethod {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 100)
}
```

In this case, although `someAsyncMethod` may have used the main thread, we didn't deadlock because we made sure the test used expectations rather than blocking the current thread.

So, bottom line, if you're testing some asynchronous methods that must use the main thread, make sure that the tests don't block, but rather that they use expectations.

---

There are, admittedly, other sources of potential problems. For example, you are calling `async` with 100 iterations. You need to be careful with that pattern, because you can easily exhaust all of the worker threads with this “thread explosion”. The attempt to introduce `concurrentPerform` (which is often used to solve thread explosion problems) won't work if the code in the closure is calling `async`.